# How to render two e-signature component in a single view/page?

Tags: javascript, extjs, html5-canvas

I am tring to create a e-signature pad component, which should be reusable. 
If I am using the component once in any page/view it's working fine.
The problem comes, when I use more than one component in a page/view. What I figured out is that there is a ID conflict for the canvas component because of which the latest rendered component only works.

Kindly help me with resolving the problem.
Refer the code below for reference:

I tried to put the ID dynamically but then some other issue came up which I am unable to figure out.

**For View:**

```
xtype: 'container',
width: 319,
reference: 'signature',
html: '<canvas id="signatureSpaceId">' + 'No Canvas Support' + '</canvas>',
listeners: {
    afterrender: 'onCanvasRendered'
}
```

**For Controller:**

```
signData: null,

init: function() {
    let controller = this;
    controller.signData = '';
},

onCanvasRendered: function() {
    var view = this.getView();

    //get the signature pad
    signPad = Ext.getDom("signatureSpaceId");
    if (signPad && signPad.getContext) {
        signPadContext = signPad.getContext('2d');
    }
    if (!signPad || !signPadContext) {
        return;
    }

    // set width and height of signature pad
    signPad.width = 300;
    signPad.height = 230;

    //Mouse events
    signPad.addEventListener('mousedown', this.eventSignPad, false);
    signPad.addEventListener('mousemove', this.eventSignPad, false);
    signPad.addEventListener('mouseup', this.eventSignPad, false);
    signPad.addEventListener('mouseout', this.eventSignPad, false);

    //Touch screen events
    signPad.addEventListener('touchstart', this.eventTouchPad, false);
    signPad.addEventListener('touchmove', this.eventTouchPad, false);
    signPad.addEventListener('touchend', this.eventTouchPad, false);

    sign = new this.signCap();
    signPadContext.lineWidth = 2;
},

signCap: function() {
    var sign = this;
    this.draw = false;
    this.start = false;
    this.mousedown = function(event) {
        signPadContext.beginPath();
        signPadContext.arc(event._x, event._y, 1, 0*Math.PI, 2*Math.PI);
        signPadContext.fill();
        signPadContext.stroke();
        signPadContext.moveTo(event._x, event._y);
        sign.draw = true;
        clearButtonMIB.enable();
        saveButtonMIB.enable();
    };
    this.mousemove = function(event) {
        if (sign.draw) {
            signPadContext.lineTo(event._x, event._y);
            signPadContext.stroke();
        }
    };
    this.mouseup = function(event) {
        if (sign.draw) {
            sign.mousemove(event);
            sign.draw = false;
        }
    };
    this.mouseout = function(event) {
        if (sign.draw) {
            sign.mousemove(event);
            sign.draw = false;
        }
    };
    this.touchstart = function(event) {
        signPadContext.beginPath();
        signPadContext.arc(event._x, event._y, 1, 0*Math.PI, 2*Math.PI);
        signPadContext.fill();
        signPadContext.stroke();
        signPadContext.moveTo(event._x, event._y);
        sign.start = true;
        clearButtonMIB.enable();
        saveButtonMIB.enable();
    };
    this.touchmove = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (sign.start) {
            signPadContext.lineTo(event._x, event._y);
            signPadContext.stroke();
        }
    };
    this.touchend = function(event) {
        if (sign.start) {
            sign.touchmove(event);
            sign.start = false;
        }
    };
},

eventSignPad: function(event) {
    if (event.offsetX || event.offsetX === 0) {
        event._x = event.offsetX;
        event._y = event.offsetY;
    } else if (event.layerX || event.layerX === 0) {
        event._x = event.layerX;
        event._y = event.layerY;
    }

    var func = sign[event.type];
    if (func) {
        func(event);
    }
},

eventTouchPad: function(event) {
    var mySign = Ext.get("signatureSpaceId");
    event._x = event.targetTouches[0].pageX - mySign.getX();
    event._y = event.targetTouches[0].pageY - mySign.getY();

    var func = sign[event.type];
    if (func) {
        func(event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might solve your problem without using ids or references. First remove the `id` property from the `canvas` element. Then adapt your `onCanvasRendered` controller method like so:

```
onCanvasRendered: function(canvasContainer) {
    ...
    signPad = canvasContainer.getEl().down('canvas', true);
    ...
}
```

You problem was getting a reference to the canvas element. Don't forget that the `afterrender` listener fires with the corresponding container as the first argument. I have called the argument `canvasContainer`. From here, using the [down](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.dom.Element.html#method-down) `Ext.dom.Element` method, you can easily get the reference to containers's descendant `canvas` element.